# How to setup Webpack to change a specific config file for dev or production?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I have 2 files, **config_local.js** and **config_prod.js**.

How would you pass in a variable into webpack to basically generate a new file named **config_api.js** from either the **local** one or the **production** one.

#### config_local.js

```
"api": {
  "login": "http://localhost/app/api/login/",
  "users": "http://localhost/app/api/users/"
}
```

#### config_prod.js

```
"api": {
  "login": "/app/api/login/",
  "users": "/app/api/users/"
}
```

Then inside of my services/api.js file

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const userLogin = (username, password) => {
    const post_data = { username, password };
    return axios.post('http://localhost/app/api/login', post_data)
        .then(res => res);
};
```

I could do something like so:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import api from 'config_api' 

export const userLogin = (username, password) => {
    const post_data = { username, password };
    return axios.post(api.login, post_data)  // <--
        .then(res => res);
};
```

Comment: You can use Environment variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In package.json you can use scripts or even at commandline you can use environment variable.s

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack",
    "production": "NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    "watch": "npm run dev -- --watch"
  },
```

In webpack.config.js you can use

```
const inProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const inDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";


if(inProduction) 
//do this
if(inDevelopment)
//do that
```

webpack by default looks for weback.config.js however for custom config you can use
`webpack --config config_local.js`

Comment: Thanks! I also want to add this link as this was the final solution I was working towards. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44371162/how-to-create-generate-export-a-file-from-my-webpack-2-config-to-be-used-inside