# How to create/generate/export a file from my webpack 2 config to be used inside of my React code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-2

I am passing in `NODE_ENV` variables into my `webpack.config` from `package.json` in order to return an object that either contains API endpoints for localhost or production.

#### 1) package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p"
}
```

#### 2) endpoints.js

```
function endpoints(env) {
    let prefix = env === 'development' ? 'http://localhost' : '';

    return {
        "login": `${prefix}/app/api/login`
    }
}

module.exports = endpoints;
```

#### 3) webpack.config

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const dist = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
const src = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");
const endpoints = require("./src/endpoints");
const api = endpoints(process.env.NODE_ENV);

console.log('webpack api', api);

module.exports = {
  context: src,
  entry: [
    "./index.js"
  ],
  output: {
    path: dist,
    // ....
```

---

Here below I can see the `console.log` of the const `api`.

[image]

---

Now my question is, how do I now generate or export out an actual file `api` to be used inside of my `src/services/api` file:

```
import axios from 'axios'
// import api from '../../webpack.config' <-- ?
// import api from '../../api.js <-- ?

const log = (method, err) => {
    console.error(`%c${method}`, 'background: #393939; color: #F25A43', err);
    return null;
};

export const userLogin = (username, password) => {
    const post_data = { username, password };
    return axios.post('http://localhost/app/api/login', post_data)  // <-- api to be used here
        .then(res => res)
        .catch((err) => log('api.userLogin', err));
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You could generate the files with a bit of Node (something like `fs.writeFileSync('api.js', contents)`, or you could do it with a bit of shell scripting, but you could also just use `env` in your code using [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) (example: `new webpack.DefinePlugin({ env: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV) })`. Then you'd be able to access `env` in your code directly.

Comment: Oh nice! Checking out DefinePlugin now, that sounds like the cleanest approach.